# How to setUp blazor for local testing that using CDN

Tags: blazor

new to Blazor development environment. I want to do use Bootstrap 4 for UI design such as using Fontawesome and other stuff that from CDN. 
Will the following be downloaded when I run app Locally with my PC connected to the Internet?

```
1.
 <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"></script>

2.
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
            integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
            crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
3.
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1"
            crossorigin="anonymous">

    </script>
4.
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM"
            crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
```

The problem: I m not getting any FontAwesome

```
<div class="col-md-6">
            <p>testing testing</p>
            <div class="media">
                <i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <div class="media-body">
                    <h5 class="mt-0">Test1</h5>
                    Desc1

                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="media">
                <i class="fa fa-dot-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <div class="media-body">
                    <h5 class="mt-0">test2</h5>
                    Desc2

                </div>
            </div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have the font-awesome css referenced by a script tag, change it to a link tag and it will work

```
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```